# AppleScript: How to search files in folder for string and show results in Finder?

Tags: finder, applescript, search, services

I am trying to create an Automator-based Service that searches my computer for the selected text. (When I say *"my computer,*" I specifically mean *Macintosh HD,* not *This Mac*, because *This Mac* includes external hard drives.)

I would like the search results to appear in a new Finder window.

Is it possible to accomplish this programmatically in Applescript or a shell script? This doesn't seem possible, but it would be ideal.

---

If this can't truly be done programmatically, then I would be okay with accomplishing this "manually." Here is an example of how that route might manifest:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    open (POSIX file "/")
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using command down
    keystroke input
end tell
```

However, I do not know how to change the search directory. (I'm trying to avert scripting mouse clicks.) By default, when a user initiates a search in Finder (e.g., when the user presses <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>), the search directory is *"This Mac,"* regardless of the directory of the Finder window that the search function was called in.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please see the section: An alternative, is to leave the default **Finder** preference for **When performing a search:** to **Searching This Mac** and do the following:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind changing a particular **Finder** preference, i.e. **When performing a search:**, then the following will work.

First, in **Finder** > **Preferences...** > **Advanced**, set **When performing a search:** to: **Search the Current Folder**

Next, create an **Automator** *Service workflow* with its default settings (Service receives selected text in any application) and add a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the default *code* with the *code* below:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        open (POSIX file "/")
    end tell
    delay 0.5 -- # Adjust as necessary or comment out/remove if not needed.
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using command down
        keystroke input as text
        keystroke return
    end tell
end run
```

Save the **Automator** *Service workflow*, e.g. **Search Selected Text in Finder**

---

If you want to add a programatic test and preference change for **When performing a search:** being set to **Search the Current Folder**, then add the following *code* directly after `on run {input, parameters}` and before the `tell application "Finder"` block.

```
if (do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder FXDefaultSearchScope") is not "SCcf" then
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder FXDefaultSearchScope SCcf; killall Finder"
    delay 1 -- # Adjust as necessary or comment out/remove if not needed.
end if
```

---

An alternative, is to leave the default **Finder** preference for **When performing a search:** to **Searching This Mac** and do the following:

- Open a new **Finder** window to the **Macintosh HD**.
- Press: **⌘F**
- On the **Search** bar, click the **“Macintosh HD”** button.
- On the **Search** bar, click the **Save** button.

Follow through to save the search. In this instance, e.g.:

- Save As: **Searching “Macintosh HD”**
- Where: **Saved Searches**
- [] Add To Sidebar (unchecked)

In the **Run AppleScript** *action* of the **Automator** *Service workflow*, replace `open (POSIX file "/")` with the following example *code*, adjusted for your system and how/where you saved the Search:

```
open POSIX file "/Users/me/Library/Saved Searches/Searching “Macintosh HD”.savedSearch"
```

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* would then be:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        open POSIX file "/Users/me/Library/Saved Searches/Searching “Macintosh HD”.savedSearch"
    end tell
    delay 0.5 -- # Adjust as necessary or comment out/remove if not needed.
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using command down
        keystroke input as text
        keystroke return
    end tell
end run
```

This latter method leaves the default setting in **Finder** alone and achieves the goal without using mouse clicks or clicking buttons from the **Automator** *Service workflow*.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and may require additional `delay` *commands* where appropriate/needed, e.g. between the `keystroke` *commands* as/if necessary.